# Universal application DB question

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm making an universal application for both iPhone and iPad and I was wondering if there is an specific location where I have to put my sqlite database? Because apperently he can't find it and giving a result of not being able to open the database! = app not working :/

Currently I have my database in the "Other Sources" folder.

```
//Maakt een lijst  van path strings voor de specifieke directories voor de specifieke domains.
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//Eerste object van paths wordt in de string gezet!
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
//er wordt gezocht naar todo.sqlite in het opgegeven path!
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"todo.sqlite"];
pad = databasePath;

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    status = TRUE; //DEBUG PURPOSES ONLY!
    const char *sql = "SELECT pk FROM todo";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            Taak *taak = [[Taak alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey database:database];
            [taken addObject:taak];
            [taak release];
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}else {
    status = FALSE; //DEBUG PURPOSES ONLY!
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

This is my connection code and I searched a lot of forums and tutorials and everyone is doing it like that!

Comment: Use Core Data unless your database is truly cross platform (between Mac/iOS and "other").  Raw SQL is a waste of time.

Comment: So what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: You should add it to the copy resources build phase. This will place it in your app bundle. You will then have to add code which detects that it isn't in the documents folder yet and copies it there before you open it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasepath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char* sqlStatement; 
        sqlStatement="select fld_carromdescription from tbl_carrom where fld_carromdetails like?";

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
        printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, & compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,[[usdflt objectForKey:@"phone"] UTF8String] , -1,SQLITE_STATIC);
            NSLog(@"Database check111");
            //  [tablearray removeAllObjects];
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                printf("in loop");

                @try {
                    NSLog(@"Database check");
                    txtview.text=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)];
                    toplbl.text=[usdflt valueForKey:@"phone"];
                    [txtview scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
                }

                @catch (NSException * e) {

                }
                @finally {

                }

            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Try this out.

I am also using the `sqliteDB` in `other sources only`. I have done 3 universal applications. I have no difficulties to get the access.